# <video> on facebook's mobile browser

Tags: html, css, webview

I have a site that uses a `<video>`.
The video is playing an mp4 file.

When I share my site on facebook messenger and the link is clicked from a mobile, Facebook opens it in it's in-app browser which doesn't play the background video.

Is there a way to get it to play videos?

Comment: Does it work on Chrome browser? Can you share the link so we can test it?

Comment: Yes it works on Chrome.
The link is davidalsh.com (my portfolio site)

Comment: It could be that the version of the browser (likely chrome) messenger uses don't support video tag.

Comment: Did you figure it out ? I have the same problem